# Variables with both 'extern' and 'inline' specifiers

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, inline, extern

I couldn't find any information on this topic neither from stackoverflow or elsewhere.
I know that `extern` can be used with namespace scope variables in header files to disambiguate a definition `int foo;` from a bare declaration `extern int foo;`. That is done to avoid breaking the one-definition-rule, in case multiple files #include this same header file.

In C++17, one can use `constexpr inline foo;` for globals, which should be better than the old way. One could *also* use `extern inline const/constexpr foo;`, both compile without errors, but I have no idea if the `extern` makes any difference semantically.

So when should one use `extern inline` with **variables**, if ever? What is the best practice in C++17?

Comment: Inline= here, extern=not here. Contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the wording [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline):

> Inline const variables at namespace scope have external linkage by default (unlike the non-inline non-volatile const-qualified variables)

It seems that there is never any need to add `extern` to an `inline const(expr)` variable.

Comment: It is used to control ODR uses.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a coder prefers to put a declaration first and a definition later. `extern` is used for this purpose. It can be applied to a declaration of an inline *variable* as well. But you will not see this in small projects.

`extern` only means that a declaration is not a definition:

```
extern int i; //declaration of i
int j;        //declare and define j to be equal to zero
```

`inline` means that the variable is inline: it can be defined in a different translation unit (TU), as long as the definition is the same, and it **must** be defined in every TU where it is ODR-used.

```
inline int k;  //declare and define k to be 0, can appear in multiple TUs
extern inline int h; //h is an inline variable but not defined
                     //it can be used to forward the definition 
int f() { return h;}
int h = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no sense by using `extern` with `inline`. I think it's strange. You'd be giving a definition for a variable that is marked as being defined elsewhere.

You're putting the variable in the translation unit with `inline`, then asking for the compiler to look for it in another translation unit with `extern`.